# Create universal binary for Mac OS with OpenJDK jpackage - application launcher is x64

Tags: java, jpackage

I'm using OpenJDK 18.0.1.1 with jlink and jpackage to create apps with a bundled JRE from our application. I'm using a new Macbook with M1 processor and I'm calling:

```
jpackage create-app-image \
-o "/Workspace/" \
-i /Workspace/installer \
-n MyAppName \
--runtime-image $RUNTIMEJDK/myruntime \
--main-class company.myapp.mainclass \
--main-jar mainclass.jar \
--icon  /Workspace/icons/MyAppName.icns \
--vendor "myCompany" \
--description "This is my application"
```

When I call

```
lipo -info /Workspace/MyAppName.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAppName
```

the architecture is x86_64. My OpenJDK is arm64.

How can I tell jpackage to create an arm64 app?

Comment: In may 2021 this has been merged into jpackage master https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/3807